# Multiple of same Render layer performance in the compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, performance

As far as performance goes, is there any penalty for duplicating the same render layer node multiple times, as opposed to using more noodles from the same node? For organizational purposes, i want to copy and paste the same render layer in a bunch of places. But will this penalize me on speed?